# How do I make a reproducible effect in Paint.NET?

Tags: post-processing, batch

I have gone through like ten steps to produce a vintage effect (or any other effect) in Paint.NET. I am wondering if there is any easy way to do all the steps again automatically for another photo. Is there any way to record a macro? Should I create a plugin for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with the ScriptLab Plugin. I see it advertised as:

> Use this plugin to create scripts and compilations of all of your other Paint.NET effects, adjustments, and plugins. You can save, load, and share your scripts.

You can pick it up at [this link](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/7291-pyrochild-plugins-2012-9-16/).

Comment: This plugin is great. Unfortunately it does not have any option to add/remove layers which is one of the requirements for creating some effects. p.s. The link you have provided strangely leads to downloading PixelLab.dll file. I could download ScriptLab.dll from [here](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/7291-pyrochild-plugins-2012-9-16/)